# How to stop duplicates caused by date range in views

Tags: 8, views

On my site I have a content type called Course. Courses can have several sessions. To display these sessions I am using the date range.

When a course has more than one date range entered an instance appears in the view for each start date.

How do I only display one instance for each course? There is only one course, even though there are multiple sessions.

The Distinct option in Query settings doesn't resolve this, nor does using Aggregation

Comment: It would help if you included a screenshot or some other representation of your current Views set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an answer to this.

To only display the first instance of each Course I needed to add a new filter to the view for **field_date_range:delta** and change the Operator to **Is equal to Value 0**.

Each Course session date range is assigned a delta number in the database. This new filter makes sure that only the first one is displayed in a view. [What does Delta mean in Drupal](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/delta/#:%7E:text=%22Delta%22%20refers%20to%20the%20order,is%20the%20third%20item%20etc.)

[image]